# How to left-align Vimeo embed

Tags: html, css, alignment, vimeo, vimeo-player

When I embed a Vimeo iFrame, the content automatically centers itself. I'd like to have control over the alignment of the iFrame and keep it to the left. (iFrames are gross.)

I've set up a flexbox container (.example-div) with two flex containers on the inside. The first container (.player-div) has the stock Vimeo iFrame player in it. The second container will ideally hold a list of credits. I can't seem to justify this iframe to the left.

HTML

```
<div class="example-div">
  <div class="player-div">
    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/142760309" frameborder="0" width="100%" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="credits-div">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.example-div {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.player-div {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 80vw;
}

.credits-div {
  background-color: green;
  width: 20vw;
}

.player-div iframe, .player-div object, .player-div embed {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

https://codepen.io/czeins/pen/dxJywB

Comment: Why not simply align the iframe instead of worrying about its content?

Comment: Ideally that's what I'd like to do. The problem is I want the iframe to be responsive, so I set its width 100%. If I don't give it a percentage width, it defaults to a very small size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is happening outside the `iframe` code completely. Flex-box doesn't respond to `width`. Inside a `display:flex` container, you should use `min/max` or `flex-basis` to set sizing... Here are [some docs](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-basis/).

Basically, your flexbox CSS should look like this:

```
.example-div {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between; // forces the two items to each side
}

.player-div {
  background-color: orange;
  flex-basis: 80%;
}

.credits-div {
  background-color: green;
  flex-basis:20%;
}
```

---

Now an iFrame with `width:100%` will fill the flex container. HOWEVER, you'll run into some additional issues because a 100% width video won't take into account different aspect ratios.

You basically need to set the height of the iFrame as well. This would be easy except for that the height of the video is actually a percentage of the now dynamic width. For example, a typical widescreen video is the ratio of 16:9 (units wide by units high). So when the width changes the height must change too.

The easiest way to do this is by creating another container like a `div` (inside the flex-container) and using absolute positioning and padding to correctly size the video.

Here's a [good explanation](https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php) of how that works and a [codepen](https://codepen.io/adrianparr/pen/GjayvV) of it in action.

Comment: Thanks for this. Definitely getting closer! Here's that in a codepen: https://codepen.io/czeins/pen/PMEZpm

Ideally, what I'd like is the following:
1) I'd like the player to be completely left-justified. I believe it's centering itself _within_ the iFrame. And then once that's resolved...
2) I'd like the player to fill the width of the .player-div up to a max-width of, say, 1000px.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you!